# SwiftUI: Listの編集モードで削除できる対象を絞る

Tags: swift, swiftui

以下の内容についてお聞きしたいです。

#### 【実現したい内容】

List表示でeditボタンを押した際に、こちらで指定した行だけ左側の削除ボタンが出て欲しいと思っています。
以下で言うと例えば0番目のtaroは削除ボタンがあって、hogeは削除ボタンがない状態にしたいです。
[image: サンプル]

#### 【コード】

上記の画像は以下のコードで作成しています。

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var persons: [Person] = [Person(name: "taro", age: 10), Person(name: "hoge", age: 15)]
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach(self.persons) { person in
          Text(person.name)
        }
        .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
          self.persons.remove(at: indexSet.first!)
        })
      }
      .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
  }
}
```

#### 【お聞きしたいこと】

1. 実現したい内容の実現方法

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`deleteDisabled(_:Bool)`と言うview modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gaugestyleconfiguration/maximumvaluelabel-swift.struct/deletedisabled(_:))がちょうどご記載の機能を実現するためのもののようです。

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var deletable: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var persons: [Person] = [
        Person(name: "taro", age: 10, deletable: true),
        Person(name: "hoge", age: 15, deletable: false),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.persons) { person in
                    Text(person.name)
                        .deleteDisabled(!person.deletable)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    self.persons.remove(at: indexSet.first!)
                })
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

SwiftUIのドキュメントの[View Modifiersのページ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gaugestyleconfiguration-maximumvaluelabel-view-modifiers)を眺めていると、意外なことが簡単に実現できそうなものが見つかったりするので、お時間のある時には時々眺めて試してみるといいかもしれません。

Comment: 解決しました、ありがとうございます。事例などを調べて行き詰まっていたのですが、公式ドキュメント当たるべきですよね。参考にさせていただきますmm